# Vertical align DIV & Text in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have gone through many questions here as well as many articles and bootstrap 4 documentation but failed to find what I'm looking for.

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/zxLLqsm0/**

I'm looking to create boxes with exact same height for all columns and also vertically center align the text inside the boxes. I managed to get the text vertically aligned but the heights of the boxes are different.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box">
        <h6>Title 1</h6>
        <p>A small description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box">
        <h6>Title 2</h6>
        <p>A bigger description goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box">
        <h6>Title 3</h6>
        <p>A large description is placed here to make whatever changes we need.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.container {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.box {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, this [question has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650798/bootstrap-4-vertical-center-equal-height-cards).

Use flexbox and `justify-content-center` to make the `box` centered, and `h-100` for `height:100%`...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box h-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
        <h6>Title 1</h6>
        <p>A small description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box h-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
        <h6>Title 2</h6>
        <p>A bigger description goes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box h-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
        <h6>Title 3</h6>
        <p>A large description is placed here to make whatever changes we need.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VsyNMHZ8VG

---

***Or,*** if you want to apply the same changes to `.box` *instead* of using the Bootstrap classes...

https://jsfiddle.net/g38e9Lfm/

```
.box {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It didn't come up in my search!

Answer (score 3):

You can add standard bootstrap classes and do not write extra css

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box d-table h-100 w-100">
        <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
          <h6>Title 1</h6>
          <p>A small description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box d-table h-100 w-100">
        <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
          <h6>Title 2</h6>
          <p>A bigger description goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="box d-table h-100 w-100">
        <div class="d-table-cell align-middle">
          <h6>Title 3</h6>
          <p>A large description is placed here to make whatever changes we need.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zxLLqsm0/53/)

Comment: I prefer the other method provided by @ZimSystem. Cleaner code but thank you. Works work beautifully too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach, hope it will help you.

```
.box{
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 200px; 
  display:table;
}
```

Wrap up your text part under a new div with class = "text", then add css

```
.text{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the class `align-item-center` for `row-eq-height`
more info: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

For understand check:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And if want vertically center align can use the next code:

```
    .box {
      background-color: grey;
      padding: 15px;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      align-items: center;
      align-content:center;
      text-align:center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```