# How to make components vertically centered with equal height column in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have applied the solution from this question: [Bootstrap 4 vertical center - equal height cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650798/bootstrap-4-vertical-center-equal-height-cards)

But, my issue is not getting solved. I can't achieve the equal height & vertically centered together though I have applied these:

```
<div class="cycle-des h-100 justify-content-center">Product Cycle</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of my issue:

[image]

Here is my [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/c5fmgxjn/11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 pr-md-0">
          <div class="cycle-des h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">Product Cycle</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 pr-md-0">
          <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
            <div class="col-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="cycle-num h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">01</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 col-lg-9">
              <div class="cycle-des h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">handloom: 4-7days</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 pr-md-0">
          <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
            <div class="col-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="cycle-num h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">02</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 col-lg-9">
              <div class="cycle-des h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">S/S MQ: 50M</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 pr-md-0">
          <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
            <div class="col-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="cycle-num h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">03</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 col-lg-9">
              <div class="cycle-des h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">S/S: 25-30days</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 pr-md-0">
          <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
            <div class="col-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="cycle-num h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">04</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 col-lg-9">
              <div class="cycle-des h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">Order MQ: 2000M</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 pr-md-0">
          <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
            <div class="col-4 col-lg-3">
              <div class="cycle-num h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">05</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 col-lg-9">
              <div class="cycle-des h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">Order delivery date: 35-50 days</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    .cycle-num, .cycle-des {
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 10px;
      display: flex;
    }
    .cycle-num {
      background-color: #666;
    }
    .cycle-des {
      background-color: #333;
    }
```

But I believe you can reduce the div's and can do it much better. Just a suggestion, you don't have to use grid classes everywhere. Just use it for the layout.

https://jsfiddle.net/mdsebans/yhcb30L5/5/